# Fancybox repeats first and last image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

You can see what I mean here: http://petrichordesign.com/photo. If you click on the link (in this case, "Battle of the Bulge, Wolfe's Pond Park," it will bring up the slide show properly. However, I have loop set to false, but you can go left from the beginning and when you get to the end, you can see the first image again. The same happens when loop is true (ie, 1-2-3-4-1-2-1-2-3-4). Here's some of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'mouseWheel'    :    true,
    'openEffect'    :   'elastic',
    'closeEffect'   :   'elastic',
    'nextEffect'    :   'fade',
    'prevEffect'    :   'fade',
    'openOpacity'   :   true,
    'closeOpacity'   :   true,
    'loop'        :   false,
  });
});
```

The HTML (it's lengthy, sorry)

```
<div class="slide"><img src="images/alison.jpg" width="825" height="378" alt="" /><span><a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" title="Alison" href="images/alisonlarge.jpg">Alison</a></span></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="images/crane.jpg" width="825" height="378" alt="" /><span><a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" title="Crane" href="images/cranelarge.jpg">Crane</a></span></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="images/vinnyangela.jpg" width="825" height="378" alt="" /><span><a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" title="Vinny, Angela, and Jess (Double Exposed)" href="images/vinnyangelalarge.jpg">Vinny, Angela, and Jess (Double Exposed)</a></span></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="images/kellie.jpg" width="825" height="378" alt="" /><span><a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" title="Kellie" href="images/kellielarge.jpg">Kellie</a></span></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="images/concourse.jpg" width="825" height="378" alt="" /><span><a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" title="Concourse, SUNY New Paltz" href="images/concourselarge.jpg">Concourse, SUNY New Paltz</a></span></div>
```

If you need to know anything else, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'loop' key into 'cyclic' with the quotes, as it says in the [Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'mouseWheel'    :    true,
        'openEffect'    :   'elastic',
        'closeEffect'   :   'elastic',
        'nextEffect'    :   'fade',
        'prevEffect'    :   'fade',
        'openOpacity'   :   true,
        'closeOpacity'   :   true,
        'cyclic'        :   false, // 'loop' to 'cyclic'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a div arround it, worked for me ;)

Like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="slide">...</div>
  <div class="slide">...</div>
</div>
```